# How to export morph changed meshes from threejs application?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, gltf

I'm trying to customize a mesh and then export it by using gltfExporter from Threejs, however it still exports with all morph/shape keys attached, I would like to remove them in the final export mesh.

Cloning the scene / mesh didn't work.

```
function exportModel() {
    var exporter = new THREE.GLTFExporter();
    if (!gltfExportEnabled) gltfExporterConfig.binary = false;

    var finalRenderModel = mainScene.children[2];
    // Remove Morph Targets
    if (!!removeExportMorphs) {
        // finalRenderModel.children[0].children[1].morphTargetDictionary = [];
        // finalRenderModel.children[0].children[1].morphTargetInfluences = [];
    }
    exporter.parse([finalRenderModel], function(gltf) {
        if (!!gltfExportEnabled) generateDownload([gltf], exportFileName + ".glb");
    }, gltfExporterConfig);
}

var generateDownload = (function() {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function(data, name) {
        var blob = new Blob(data, { type: "octet/stream" }),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = name;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());
```

Mesh gets exported with all morphs/shape keys attached or does not get exported

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you additionally execute this code:

```
finalRenderModel.children[0].children[1].geometry.morphAttributes = {};
```

Morph attributes are assigned to the geometry. `Mesh.morphTargetInfluences` and `Mesh.morphTargetDictionary` are generated based on these geometry data when a new instance of `Mesh` is created.

`three.js R107`

Comment: Hi @Mugen87, thanks for the reply, but unfortunately, not yet, I even tried with all three variables:

finalRenderModel.children[0].children[1].morphTargetDictionary = [];
finalRenderModel.children[0].children[1].morphTargetInfluences = [];
finalRenderModel.children[0].children[1].geometry.morphAttributes = {};

But it still get same issue, or the model gets exported with morphs included with it, or it doesn't get exported containing the changes in the object, I'm guessing if there's any way to clone the visible mesh to export somehow. ( skipping morph keys on the export )